# Merge two javascript object using common properties using node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have two object with some similer key values osmstartnode and osmendnode. i want to merge these two object and get the final object with new value having congestion_level.

**First object**

```
var object = [{
    osmstartnode: 370705004,
    osmendnode: 1369956654,
    congestion_level: 1
  },
  {
    osmstartnode: 42469049,
    osmendnode: 42469053,
    congestion_level: 2
  }
];
```

**Second object**

```
var roadobjt = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [-74.0048445, 40.7124759],
        [-74.0048533, 40.71245],
        [-74.0048604, 40.7124243],
        [-74.0048578, 40.7123974],
        [-74.0048468, 40.7123722],
        [-74.0048252, 40.7123472],
        [-74.0045725, 40.7121422]
      ]
    },
    properties: {
      "osmhighway": "motorway_link",
      "osmoneway": "yes",
      "osmwayid": 5669636,
      "osmstartnode": 370705004,
      "osmendnode": 1369956654,
      "speed_mean_mph": 16,
      "pct_from_freeflow": 72,
      "speed_freeflow_mph": 22
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [-73.99866284812883, 40.59729307801823],
        [-73.99879364640618, 40.59716957964474],
        [-73.99913817998096, 40.596844447960684],
        [-73.99931411513008, 40.596676614430145]
      ]
    },
    properties: {
      "osmname": "Bay Parkway",
      "osmhighway": "primary",
      "osmoneway": "no",
      "osmwayid": 5675398,
      "osmstartnode": 42469049,
      "osmendnode": 42469053,
      "speed_mean_mph": 20,
      "pct_from_freeflow": 67,
      "speed_freeflow_mph": 29
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried and we'll be happy to help with specific questions or problems you have.

Comment: the items you call object is actually an array of objects

Comment: Idea (modified merge sort): Sort both arrays by the pair of `osmstartnode`, `osmendnode` using `Array.sort` with a custom comparison function. Then iterate over both arrays in parallel and upon encountering a match, complement the objects according to your specs. The order of the sort keys of the current objects in both arrays tells you on which array to select the next iteration element.

Comment: Are you saying you want to merge the objects in arr 1 into the objects in arr2, specifically the propperies object in the arr2 object - of the same index of arr1?

Comment: @developer yea i want to merge in this nested object of second object 'properties'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to merge use:

```
var object = [{
    osmstartnode: 370705004,
    osmendnode: 1369956654,
    congestion_level: 1
  },
  {
    osmstartnode: 42469049,
    osmendnode: 42469053,
    congestion_level: 2
  }
];
```

into properties of:

```
var roadobjt = [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [-74.0048445, 40.7124759],
        [-74.0048533, 40.71245],
        [-74.0048604, 40.7124243],
        [-74.0048578, 40.7123974],
        [-74.0048468, 40.7123722],
        [-74.0048252, 40.7123472],
        [-74.0045725, 40.7121422]
      ]
    },
    properties: {
      "osmhighway": "motorway_link",
      "osmoneway": "yes",
      "osmwayid": 5669636,
      "osmstartnode": 370705004,
      "osmendnode": 1369956654,
      "speed_mean_mph": 16,
      "pct_from_freeflow": 72,
      "speed_freeflow_mph": 22
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [-73.99866284812883, 40.59729307801823],
        [-73.99879364640618, 40.59716957964474],
        [-73.99913817998096, 40.596844447960684],
        [-73.99931411513008, 40.596676614430145]
      ]
    },
    properties: {
      "osmname": "Bay Parkway",
      "osmhighway": "primary",
      "osmoneway": "no",
      "osmwayid": 5675398,
      "osmstartnode": 42469049,
      "osmendnode": 42469053,
      "speed_mean_mph": 20,
      "pct_from_freeflow": 67,
      "speed_freeflow_mph": 29
    }
  }
];
```

use :

```
roadobjt.map((r, i) => { r.properties = Object.assign(r.properties, object[i]); return r;})
```

results:

```
[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-74.0048445,40.7124759],[-74.0048533,40.71245],[-74.0048604,40.7124243],[-74.0048578,40.7123974],[-74.0048468,40.7123722],[-74.0048252,40.7123472],[-74.0045725,40.7121422]]},"properties":{"osmhighway":"motorway_link","osmoneway":"yes","osmwayid":5669636,"osmstartnode":370705004,"osmendnode":1369956654,"speed_mean_mph":16,"pct_from_freeflow":72,"speed_freeflow_mph":22,"congestion_level":1}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-73.99866284812883,40.59729307801823],[-73.99879364640618,40.59716957964474],[-73.99913817998096,40.596844447960684],[-73.99931411513008,40.596676614430145]]},"properties":{"osmname":"Bay Parkway","osmhighway":"primary","osmoneway":"no","osmwayid":5675398,"osmstartnode":42469049,"osmendnode":42469053,"speed_mean_mph":20,"pct_from_freeflow":67,"speed_freeflow_mph":29,"congestion_level":2}}]
```